# checking if an attachment already exist given custom object

Tags: attachment, bulk-api, python

I am using python code with the SalesforceBulkpy API to upload an image to a custom object. 
I want to make sure I only upload the image once so I thought on adding a check if an image exists before trying to upload it.

I am using the following code

```
query_url ='M_YSF_URL/services/data/v37.0/query/?explain=
response = requests.get(
   query_url+
   'select+id+from+Attachment+where+ParentId='+
    parent_id,
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s'%session_id}
 )
```

but I am always getting

```
<Response [400]>
```

and if I try to access the url of the query with the parentID and such I am getting

```
<Errors>
<Error>
<errorCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</errorCode>
<message>Session expired or invalid</message>
</Error>
</Errors>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll want to check `session_id`; it appears that it is None (no value), which would explain the error you're getting.

Comment: session_id is not none. I guess this is the reason for the issue with trying to access it in the browser cause I am doing

Comment: M_YSF_URL/services/data/v37.0/query/?explain= select+id+from+Attachment+where+ParentId=PID
without specifying the Session in the url

but still this request is not working in python